# How to build static library using RAD Studio 2010?

Tags: dll, c++builder, static-linking, c++builder-2010

I have been confused by C++ Builder 2010 assuming my library is dynamic. I did not find any options or help in documents regarding what I need to change in the project to build static library.

Now I produce DLL, but I need to produce LIB, so I can just link it to the project and forgot about DLL. BTW it produces LIB, but for dynamic linkage only.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried Project Props -> Config properties -> Config Type -> Static library (.lib) ?

Comment: Thanks man i really stuck with this thing. I do not know for what this props is made for. Can you please descriebe more detail, how to find this menu?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but AFAIK Delphi 2010 doesn't support .bpi (static) files.  It was removed at some point.  This has been a ballache for us too, as we have a large project that we want to break down into units and for various reasons dynamic libraries won't cut it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose "Static Library" when you create the project. You can't convert it once the project already exists. This will create a statically linked library. It should be easy to add your existing source files to the new project and just build.